# how to split a string into substrings in haskell

Tags: haskell

Please help me solve this problem, I have been sitting on it for a long time. So far, only    this has occurred to me, but I do not know how to group it further.

Implement a function nSubstrings :: String -> Int -> [String] which returns the list of the n-substrings of a string.

something like:

```
    nSubstrings "HASKELLISFUN" 0 = []
    nSubstrings "HASKELLISFUN" 1 = ["HASKELLISFUN"]
    nSubstrings "HASKELLISFUN" 5 = ["HLU","ALN","SI","KS","EF"]
```

I tried to group them into pairs and then sort by key.
for example nSubstrings "HASKELLISFUN" 3

[('H',1),('A',2),('S',3),('K',1),('E',2),('L',3),('L',1),('I',2),('S',3),('F',1),('U',2),('N',3)]
I would like to see it like this
[('H',1),('K',1)('L',1),('F',1)('A',2),('E',2),('I',2),('U',2),('S',3),('L',3),,('S',3),('N',3)]
to do this, I wrote this code

```
    nSubstrings xs n 
                | n==0 = []
                | otherwise =   splitOnPairs xs --groupBy (\(x,y) -  > y == y) $ splitOnPairs xs
                    where splitOnPairs xs = [x | let y = [1..n], x<- zip xs $ cycle y ]
```

maybe someone will give advice or a solution. I will be very grateful.

Comment: What di you try? What is not working?

Comment: `nSubstrings xs n 
                | n==0 = []
                | otherwise =  sortAndGroup $ splitOnPairs xs --groupBy (\(x,y) -> y == y) $ splitOnPairs xs
                    where splitOnPairs xs = [x | let y = [1..n], x<- zip xs $ cycle y ]
                          sortAndGroup assocs = `

I don't quite understand now how to group them

Comment: You can use that [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74614919/edit) link to add code to your post.

Comment: I tried to group them into pairs. And then sort by key.
`[('H',1),('A',2),('S',3),('K',1),('E',2),('L',3),('L',1),('I',2),('S',3),('F',1),('U',2),('N',3)]`

Comment: @VladislavTikhonov: please *edit* the question with the attempt.

Comment: I have corrected the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a [**`sortOn :: Ord b => (a -> b) -> [a] -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:sortOn) to first sort this on the second item, and then produce "bursts" of items with the same group with [**`groupBy :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [[a]]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:groupBy), here we thus work with the second item in the 2-tuple. Finally we need to perform a mapping on all items to obtain the `Char`, not a tuple `(Char, Int)`:

```
import Data.List(groupBy, sortOn)

nSubstrings :: [a] -> Int -> [[a]]
nSubstrings xs n
  | n==0 = []
  | otherwise = map (map …) (groupBy (\(_, x) (_, y) -> …) (sortOn … splitOnPairs))
  where splitOnPairs xs = zip xs (cycle [1 .. n])
```

where you still need to fill in the `…` parts.